# Best practice for useEffect for a update action you want to use in multiple places in code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have a useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getMarket(web3, marketaddress, marketindex).then(setMarket);
}, [web3Ref, marketaddress, marketindex]);
```

This works OK, but now say I need to have this line in a few places (because various async actions require a refresh of the market:

```
  getMarket(web3, marketaddress, marketindex).then(setMarket);
```

Are there any better options than what I can think of:

1. Copy and paste `getMarket(web3, marketaddress, marketindex).then(setMarket);` in each place.
2. Declare a function, but because of the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps I will get a lint error unless the function is a static outside of the component, in which case it would need to take setMarket as an argument, which seems silly.
3. Use an additional piece of pseudo-state to track changes, e.g. a number called version. Increment it whenever I want to refresh and then add this as a dependency to the `useEffect` above. Something like:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      getMarket(web3, marketaddress, marketindex).then(setMarket);
    }, [web3Ref, marketaddress, marketindex, changeIndex]);
```

Is there a better/alternative way than anything I have described?

Comment: For 2, as I understand it if I did declare the function inside the component, it would change on every render, which means the refresh is done on every render.

Comment: maybe you can define your hook for this?

Comment: `getMarket` is *already* just a function. How much simpler are you trying to make the code? How many more places are you calling `getMarket` and enqueueing a state update? Regarding #2.... that wouldn't be much different than the code is already doing now, and I'd argue passing `setMarket` as an argument would be more clean than using the Promise chain externally. I say this only because it seems there's already heavy coupling between `getMarket` and a "market" state. #3 seems the least ideal pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom hook with **refetch data**

```
const useMarket = (web3, marketaddress, marketindex) => {
  const [market, setMarket] = useState();
  const fetchMarket = useCallback(
    () => getMarket(web3, marketaddress, marketindex).then(setMarket),
    [marketaddress, marketindex, web3]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMarket();
  }, [marketaddress, marketindex, fetchMarket]);

  return { market, refetch: fetchMarket };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a custom hook which you can import to all your components, a custom hook can use its own state so there's no need to send the setState function.

It would look something like this:

```
//useMarket.js

const useMarket = (web3, marketaddress, marketindex)=>{

    const [market, setMarket] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        getMarket(web3, marketaddress, marketindex).then(setMarket);
    }, [web3Ref, marketaddress, marketindex]);

    return market;
}

export default useMarket;
```

That's it based on the info you provided, now I'll give some advice which comes to mind but may be not so useful for you.

- I usually use named parameters in hooks so I can edit them later withou having to change every place I use them, so the declaration would be like     `const useMarket = ({web3, marketaddress, marketindex})`
- It seems to me that `web3` is the the js library to communicate with a blockchain, so you may find a better way to get inside the hook so you don't need to send it every time you call it.
- If you call this in many components that require the same info, I would suggest to use come kind of cache inside you hook to prevent several api calls for the same information
- You can change what you return to be an object if you want to expose something more than just the `market` state. Something like the setter, or the cache control methods if you happen to implement it.
- You're actual code is missing error handling, so you could return another variable with a "state" of the hook, there you may tell the ui if it's loading or if there was an error getting the data

Comment: web3 is an instance of the library - it can change, I am not near the code now but for example it might change if you change to a different network e.g. main net to a test net. I prefer to assume it might change, and that if it does a whole bunch of stuff on my page will need to react to that. web3 here is simply the object in web3Ref, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

#3. People expect useEffect() to alter state so this is the ideal place for your code.

You can introduce a `const [marketIsDirty, setMarketIsDirty] = useState(true)` and if a user action or external condition should cause the market to be updated, call `setMarketIsDirty(true)` to trigger the state refresh.

call inside useEffect, `setMarketIsDirty(false)` once you've updated the market.

Also, do not update the market when marketIsDirty is false to avoid infinite loops.

Better, introduce a 'marketState' state with an enumeration of DIRTY, UPDATING, SUCCESS, ERROR so you can manage the UI in concert with the state changes.